# Using a JNDI datasource can I get the connection string from it?

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat6, jndi

I have my application on Tomcat with a JNDI datasource. I need to access the connection string from it. Is there a way to do that in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
DataSource ds ...
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
DatabaseMetadata dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
System.out.println(dbmd.getURL());
```

You can get more info of DataBaseMetadata chedk this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html